# How do I write to an IIS webdav share?

Tags: macos, file-sharing, webdav

I'm trying to connect to a WebDAV share on a windows computer. My computer is running OSX 10.5, and while it connects, every write gives me an error:

> The Finder cannot complete the operation because some data in "**filename**" could not be read or written.
>   (Error code -36)

Windows boxes can read and write just fine to the share. I thought OSX supported WebDAV?

Answer (score -1):

This is for an older version of OSX but it is related to the error code you're getting. Mac [OS X 10.4: Error -36 alert displays when connecting to a Windows server](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1564)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is specifically WebDAV not SMB/CIFS.